# Compare two CSVs

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have two CSV . let me name them A and B. A has 70000 approx values with 20 columns and B have 1000 values with 10 columns.
Both share one common column 'ID'. Now I want to search for those 1000 items in A. If they exist in A, I want to get the values/rows of only those items from A. with all 20 columns.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951992/compare-two-csv-in-excel#comment113088253_63951992).

Still. In the hope you will edit your question according to *"[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"*, I will provide an answer so others can be helped as well.

One can use the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(F2,,,COUNTA(F2:F)),A2:D,{1,2,3,4},0),))
```

[image]

If you refer to separate spreadsheets, you should use `IMPORTRANGE`
in place of `A2:D`

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`OFFSET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379)
- [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991)
- [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)

Answer (score 0):

- In 21st (U) column of file A: `=match(ID,fileB!ID:ID,0)`
- In 22nd (V) columns of file A: `=index(fileB!A:A,$U:$U)`
- In 23rd-41st columns of file A: copy formula from column (V)

Still, an example would help everyone!